# Как отправить данные через POST thymeleaf form без формы ввода данных

Tags: java, thymeleaf

Пишу программку, где клиент при входе получает список предложений и может выбрать одно из них. Данные на страницу передаются списком через model.addAttribute("offers", viewOffers)

```
<table class="table table-sm table-hover align-middle">
<thead>
<tr>
    <th scope="col">сумма(руб.)</th>
    <th scope="col">Проценты(%)</th>
    <th scope="col">Срок(лет)</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<th:block th:each="viewOffer : ${offers}">
    <tr>
        <td  th:text="${viewOffer.sum}">сумма</td>
        <td th:text="${viewOffer.percentage}">процент</td>
        <td  th:text="${viewOffer.term}">срок</td>
        <td>
            <div class="d-grid gap-2 d-md-block">
                <form action="#" th:action="@{/service/offerDetails}" th:object="${viewOffer}" method="post">
                    <input type="hidden" th:value="${viewOffer.sum}" />
                    <input type="hidden" th:value="${viewOffer.percentage}" />
                    <input type="hidden" th:value="${viewOffer.term}" />
                    <button type="submit" name="submit" value="Подробнее">Подробнее</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</th:block>
</tbody>
```

Модель совсем простая.

```
@NoArgsConstructor
public class ViewOffer {
    public int sum;
    public double percentage;
    public int term;
}
```

Данные на странице отображаются, но при нажатии кнопки они не передаются в @PostMapping(объект с пустыми значениями).

```
@PostMapping(value = "/offerDetails")
public String issueCredit(@ModelAttribute ViewOffer viewOffer, Model model)
```

С thymeleaf дружу плохо. Все примеры в интернете описывают поля для ввода, а у меня по сути полей нет, а уже готовые данные. Буду рад любому ответу. Спасибо.

Comment: Было бы здорово ещё увидеть код модели, ну а вообще проблема у вас в том, что у input отсутствует атрибут name в котором вы должны передать ключ по которому прочитаете данные на сервере.
Так как ключей нет, вы получаете (объект с пустыми значениями)

Comment: Спасибо, я правильно понял, что итоговый вид должен быть примерно таким?
<input type="hidden" name="sum" th:value="${viewOffer.sum}" />

Comment: Да, правильно, прикрепил в ответе пример, скорее всего для тебя он будет рабочий

Answer (score 0):

```
<table class="table table-sm table-hover align-middle">
<thead>
<tr>
    <th scope="col">сумма(руб.)</th>
    <th scope="col">Проценты(%)</th>
    <th scope="col">Срок(лет)</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<th:block th:each="viewOffer : ${offers}">
    <tr>
        <td  th:text="${viewOffer.sum}">сумма</td>
        <td th:text="${viewOffer.percentage}">процент</td>
        <td  th:text="${viewOffer.term}">срок</td>
        <td>
            <div class="d-grid gap-2 d-md-block">
                <form action="#" th:action="@{/service/offerDetails}" th:object="${viewOffer}" method="post">
                    <input name="sum" type="hidden" th:value="${viewOffer.sum}" />
                    <input name="percentage" type="hidden" th:value="${viewOffer.percentage}" />
                    <input name="term" type="hidden" th:value="${viewOffer.term}" />
                    <button type="submit" name="submit" value="Подробнее">Подробнее</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</th:block>
</tbody>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, но к сожалению результат тот же, все поля пустые(т.е. дефолтные - 0)

Answer (score 0):

Нашел решение. В модель добавляем гетеры и сеттеры в саму форму в input добавляем id

```
<table class="table table-sm table-hover align-middle">
<thead>
<tr>
    <th scope="col">сумма(руб.)</th>
    <th scope="col">Проценты(%)</th>
    <th scope="col">Срок(лет)</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<th:block th:each="viewOffer : ${offers}">
    <form action="#" th:action="@{/service/offerDetails}" th:object="${viewOffer}" method="post">
    <tr>
        <td  th:text="${viewOffer.sum}">сумма</td>
        <td th:text="${viewOffer.percentage}">процент</td>
        <td  th:text="${viewOffer.term}">срок</td>
        <td>
            <div class="d-grid gap-2 d-md-block">
                    <input name="sum" id="sum" th:value="${viewOffer.sum}" type="hidden"/>
                    <input name="percentage" id="percentage" th:value="${viewOffer.percentage}" type="hidden"/>
                    <input name="term" id="term" th:value="${viewOffer.term}" type="hidden"/>
                    <button type="submit" value="Подробнее">Подробнее</button>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    </form>
</th:block>
</tbody>
```